# Magento 2.4.2 Body Tag Empty

Tags: magento2, css, magento2.4.2, dynamic, magento2.4.2-p1

Trying to update one site from 2.4.0-p1 to 2.4.2-p1 and another from 2.3.6 to 2.4.2-p1

Both Magento instances now don't add anything to the Body Tag?

Before:

```
<body data-container="body" class="cms-home cms-index-index page-layout-1column">
```

Now:

```
<body>
```

I can see it flashing in the dev tools as though something is manipulating it, but nothing happens.

I have removed all custom modules and theming.

Has anyone experienced this as without these CSS classes my styling breaks!

Thanks,

Comment: have you check the log on the console or log files?

Comment: There is no errors that I can see relate to it, however if I go onto sources and check the body tag there as apposed to the 'Elements' tab I can see the body is correct?

 <body data-container="body"
    
        id="html-body" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemscope="itemscope" class="page-product-configurable catalog-product-view product-test categorypath-womens category-womens page-layout-1column">